# Implement custom tab bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, tween

How do I implement this kind of tab bar and tab bar view in flutter. When user swipe left the tab change to dog and the dog product get bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the easier way to accomplish that design is to couple a slider with a top bar and bind the indexes.

You could start by using a [slider package](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider), customize it to look exactly like your design.
Then you add a Row on top of it with your categories and bind the `onPressed` from this row of buttons to jump on the desired index in the slider.